# ICE Faces fileInput file path and file name properties

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, icefaces

I'd like to utilize an ICE Faces fileInput control to fill in the file path & file name for the input to an input field on a web page based on file that the user selects. How can I capture these properties without actually performing any file transfer operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the real answer is that you can't.  The file path won't be sent by the browser for security reasons.  The file name will be sent, however I don't believe it gets sent without an actual upload.

The closest you could come, afaik, would be to forcibly kill the connection just when the upload starts.  That would net you the filename with little actual transferred data, but it doesn't sound like it would be useful to you.

Alternatively, a signed Java applet might get you closer to a solution that you'd want.